# Hide img alt tag on image hover in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the browser popup that shows up when I hover my images that have `alt` attribute.

I need this attribute to still be on the html pages, so it's indexed by Google, but I don't want users to see it when they hover the image.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the `title` attribute?  The `alt` attribute [does nothing](https://jsfiddle.net/m599b0dp/).

Comment: i thought it was title that showed upon hover, and alt only if the image fails to load...

Comment: `$("[title]").attr("title","")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quick and dirty, but it will get rid of all the alt attributes on images.

```
[].forEach.call(document.images, function(img) {
  img.setAttribute('alt', '');
});
```

As Scott pointed out, the alt attribute isn't the one responsible for showing text on hover. You can easily change the script to remove either.

```
[].forEach.call(document.images, function(img) {
  img.title = ''; // this property style syntax works too
});
```

Comment: I think it's the `title` attribute the OP is hunting down, but your script can be easily modified to support this.  +1

Comment: Going to have to move this thread to codegolf.stackexchange if you're not careful with these suggestions...

Comment: In ES6, you can shorten the whole thing to `[].forEach.call(document.images, i => i.title = '');`, but this is getting ridiculous, aha

Comment: Couldn't resist an ES7 version: `[for (i of document.images) i.title]`. Although I guess that depends on whether HTMLCollections will have iterable interfaces.